# Does the Copy Editor badge exclude tag-only edits or tag wiki edits?

Tags: support, tags, edits, badges, edit-badges

The [Copy Editor badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/65/copy-editor) has the following description:

> Edit 500 posts (excluding own or deleted posts **and tag edits**).

(emphasis mine). This is unclear to me. Does "tag edits" refer to edits that only modify a question's tags, or edits to tag wikis and excerpts?

Comment: This is clearly explained in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/188732/377214) to [What are the badges I can earn on each site, and what are the exact criteria for earning each badge?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/what-are-the-badges-i-can-earn-on-each-site-and-what-are-the-exact-criteria-for)

Comment: That said, it may be worth modifying the description to say "tag-only edits".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes and No. (You asked two questions in the title)

The first Yes is the answer to "it excludes tag-only edits", or equivalently, any edit that only changes tags of a question. (It's not possible to perform a tag edit on an answer, apparently).

The second No is the answer to "it excludes tag-wiki edits". An edit to a tag wiki or a tag wiki excerpt counts toward the S & W and the Copy Editor badge. If you edit both the wiki and the excerpt at once, they count as 2 edits to the progress of those badges.

More details >>> https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/188732